# How do I permutate a binary string of 30 characters and omit "bad strings"

Tags: python, permutation

I input the length of the string (10 or 30 or ...) and input the "bad strings" "101", "111", and count the number of permutations that do not contain bad strings.

I tried this with itertools and it worked fine for string that are 10-15, but for 30, its well over a trillion results and cannot run efficiently. I think the method is to build the string one char at a time, but I cant figure out the algorithm to do this.

```
import itertools
v1="111"
v2="101"
def perms(n):
    for i in range(2**n):
        s=bin(i)[2:]
        s="0"*(n-len(s)) + s
        if v1 not in s and v2 not in s:
            print(s)
            yield s
print len(list(perms(10)))
```

Comment: for a length of 10, you should get 169 results out of a possible 1024 total permutations. i.e. 2^n where n is the length of the binary string.

Comment: Do you know the length of the bad strings?

Comment: So do you expect from this to print 0?

Comment: Patrick - yes, the bad strings are 111 and 101. So if badstring not in binary string, add to the counter.

Stam - The counter should be 169 for the test case of length 10 and the bad strings above.

Comment: Where is the binary string that you permutate?

Comment: all permutations of length 10: 0000000000 to 1111111111 and everything in between.

Comment: That's not permutations.

Comment: Okay edited above is a working example for length 10. but if I try this for length 30, it will take for every to do. Im trying to find the other way to achieve this.

Comment: When the length is 30, I get 2550409 strings. It takes almost 42 seconds on this 2GHz 32 bit machine.

Comment: @PM2Ring What code did you use for that? On my 3.9GHz i7-6700 it takes about 8 minutes (the current OP code with removed printing).

Comment: @StefanPochmann: See my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution. It runs *slightly* faster on my ancient machine than Stefan's code.

We iterate over the numbers, using the `str.format` method to convert them to bitstrings. When we find a bitstring with a bad pattern we jump ahead to the first number that doesn't contain that pattern at that bit position. So if we find a bad pattern ending at the `2**0` bit position (the LSB) of the bitstring we advance by 1, if the bad pattern ends at the `2**1` bit position we advance by 2, etc.

Here's a version with a print call in the loop so we can see what's happening.

```
def skip_bad(width, bad=("101", "111")):
    n = 0
    while n < 1<<width:
        s = '{0:0{1}b}'.format(n, width)
        for b in bad:
            i = s.find(b)
            if i != -1:
                i = width - i - len(b)
                print('skipping', s, i)
                n += 1 << i
                break
        else:
            yield s
            n += 1

for i in skip_bad(5):
    print(i)
```

**output**

```
00000
00001
00010
00011
00100
skipping 00101 0
00110
skipping 00111 0
01000
01001
skipping 01010 1
01100
skipping 01101 0
skipping 01110 1
10000
10001
10010
10011
skipping 10100 2
11000
11001
skipping 11010 1
skipping 11100 2
```

Here's the version I used to get the timing data given in the comments.

```
def skip_bad(width, bad=("101", "111")):
    n = 0
    while n < 1<<width:
        s = '{0:0{1}b}'.format(n, width)
        for b in bad:
            i = s.find(b)
            if i != -1:
                n += 1 << (width - i - len(b))
                break
        else:
            yield s
            n += 1

width = 30
print(width)
print(sum(1 for _ in skip_bad(width)))
```

**output**

```
30
2550409
```

Comment: Neat. I think I briefly thought of something like this but immediately rejected it as too complicated. Nice to see it isn't.

Comment: On my PC it's faster if I use `s = bin(n + (1 << width))[3:]` (about 4.2 seconds instead of 5.6 seconds).

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Interesting! I didn't think of forcing the correct width with `1 << width`.

Comment: Btw, which of my versions did you measure? On my PC, my iterative versions are a bit faster than yours (they take me about 3.4 seconds).

Comment: @StefanPochmann I only timed the very first version you posted. When I saw the timing info from your machine I almost didn't bother posting my code, thinking that it must be vastly inferior to yours... until I timed your code on my old clunker. :)

Comment: Haha, ok :-). Got yours down to 4.0 seconds now with `s = bin(n)` and `n += 1 << (len(s) - i - len(b))`, that's just not valid if he changes the "bad" strings to include one starting with a zero.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Good point. I didn't even consider "bad" strings starting with a zero... I'm tempted to convert the "bad" strings back to `int`s so I can use Python 3's `int.bit_length` on them. :)

Comment: Found a way to make yours faster than mine: `s = bin(n)` and `if b in s: n += 1 << (len(s) - s.find(b) - len(b))`. Takes me about 3.0 seconds with that.

Comment: Oh, but that still relies on bad strings starting with '1'. Anyway, you could use `in` like that as well, it's a big improvement.

Comment: Nice, this works really fast. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Nice. FWIW, I was considering caching the lengths of the bad words, but I figured that looking up those lengths in a list would probably take just as long as the `len` call, since that's rather fast.

Comment: Thanks, @nicholasordonia I wish I could split the "accept" with Stefan, but SO doesn't work like that.

Comment: Ah, you just gave me another idea. Down to about 2.75 seconds by preparing and using local variables `_bin, _len, N = bin, len, 1 << width` :-)

Comment: Also could you briefly explain how this works? I dont really understand the << notation. Python is new for me.

Comment: @StefanPochmann and PM2Ring Both answers are great. Just accepted the first as the answer. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the strings bit by bit, avoiding bad paths right away. Here's an iterative version:

```
def build(n):
    strings = ['']
    bad = '111', '101'
    for _ in range(n):
        strings = [s + bit
                   for s in strings
                   for bit in '01'
                   if not (s + bit).endswith(bad)]
    return strings
```

That confirms the 169 for 10 bits in a split second and takes about 3.4 seconds to find me the 2550409 strings with 30 bits.

```
>>> len(build(10))
169
>>> len(build(30))
2550409
```

Can also use nested generators to save memory:

```
def build(n):
    strings = ['']
    bad = '111', '101'
    for _ in range(n):
        strings = (s + bit
                   for s in strings
                   for bit in '01'
                   if not (s + bit).endswith(bad))
    return strings
```

Demo, also takes me about 3.4 seconds:

```
>>> len(list(build(30)))
2550409
```

Alternatively, a recursive version:

```
def build(n, prefix=''):
    if n == 0:
        yield prefix
        return
    for bit in '01':
        if not (prefix + bit).endswith(('111', '101')):
            yield from build(n - 1, prefix + bit)
```

Finds me the 2550409 for 30 bits in about seven seconds:

```
>>> len(list(build(30)))
2550409
```

For Python 2, replace the `yield from` line with this:

```
            for bits in build(n - 1, prefix + bit):
                yield bits
```

If I pass around an output list instead of yielding through all the levels, it takes me about 4.5 seconds:

```
def build(n, output, prefix=''):
    if n == 0:
        output.append(prefix)
        return
    for bit in '01':
        if not (prefix + bit).endswith(('111', '101')):
            build(n - 1, output, prefix + bit)
```

Demo:

```
>>> output = []
>>> build(30, output)
>>> len(output)
2550409
```

Comment: FWIW, `sum(1 for _ in build(n))` is _slightly_ slower than `len(list(build(n)))` but it avoids eating up all that RAM. Of course, the RAM used by that list is reclaimed almost immediately, but still..

Comment: @PM2Ring Right... I guess I did it with `list` because that's how the OP did it and because it's just simpler. Anyway, that's just the demo usage, not the solution itself (except for the iterative version I just added (of which I'll add a generators version now :-)).

Comment: How does this differ from my code sample? How does it run it faster? Im new to python and want to understand how this works.

Comment: @nicholasordonia Yours goes through **all** possible strings and looks for good ones. Mine only goes through good strings (and their prefixes).